# How do I use "Printout3D" command to obtain a 3D printable file from DensityPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, 3d-printing

I am trying to make [`DensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot3D.html) from a model function `a*x+(y*z)` to be exported to .stl. The parameter `a` is unique for several materials to be considered, hence, it makes life easier for me to use [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) so that I can change the values of `a` for the materials (there are lot of them). This is my code:

```
 Manipulate[DensityPlot3D[a*x+(y*z),{x,0,2}, {y,0,2},{z,1,10}],{a, 1, 5}]
```

Unfortunately, even using `Export["model.stl", model]` failed. This is why I am considering using `"Printout3D"` possibly within the code. I don't know how this could be done and would love to have your inputs and suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: If you had taken the [tour], as you should, you would have learned that is off-topic to ask questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer. Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because it's not clear what you need. To avoid or revert the Hold you can [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and make it specific, well structured and easy to understand. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Comment: Since you have not included the code that generates your manipulation, it is impossible to give you a specific answer. A general but very vague answer is that you should add a `Button` expression that has an action (2nd agument) that calls `Export` to output whatever it is that you want to write to disk. The `Button` expression is likely to need the option `Method -> Queued` because `Export` can be slow.

Comment: Thanks rhermans for the encouragement. I have made modifications to my question and I am sorry for the ambiguities in the earlier form of the question.

Comment: Thanks m_goldberg. I have now included the code and would be very happy to have your opinion once again.

Comment: @Dean first off, you won't be able to export the `Manipulate` directly. What you can do is create a list of files, though, for different values of `a`. You're also going to run into trouble with the opacity. How do you want to handle that? My assumption is you'll need to use `RegionPlot3D` in the end.

Comment: @b3m2a1, thank you for the important information!

Comment: Dean, can you unaccept my answer and accept Chip Hurst's? His approach is in fact the correct way to do this and mine is just a bad approximation of his.

Comment: @b3m2a1, done! Your contribution is still an excellent one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the cutoff idea from b3m2a1:

```
plot = With[{a = 1, cutoff = .5},
  DensityPlot3D[a*x + (y*z),
    {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 1, 10},
    OpacityFunction -> Function[If[# < cutoff, 0, 1]]
  ]
];
```

We can turn this raster into an image, and then a mesh:

```
data = Reverse[plot[[1, 1]], {1, 2}];
ImageMesh[Image3D[data]]
```

[image]

We can smooth it with marching cubes:

```
ImageMesh[Image3D[data], Method -> "MarchingCubes"]
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely the right way to go. I asked the OP to accept this so future visitors to the page see it. Very cool. And I'd never have thought to check `ImageMesh` for a `Method` so very cool on that as well.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in a comment, there are two issues with your current workflow.

For one, you won't be able to generate the STL directly from the `Manipulate`. Instead we'll need to make a list of objects to export.

For another, the `Opacity` in the `DensityPlot3D` means that it's not really a solid in any sense. My interpretation of your problem is that you want the hull of the thing generated, i.e. you effectively want the result from:

```
With[{a = 1, cutoff = .5},
 DensityPlot3D[a*x + (y*z),
  {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 1, 10},
  OpacityFunction -> Function[If[# < cutoff, 0, 1]]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: blah]

The cleanest way to get this that I can think of in a general manner is to directly generate the [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html) from this. For that reason I wrote a little wrapper function to generate that:

```
Options[regionHull] =
  Join[
   {
    "CutoffFunction" -> (# > .5 &),
    "CutoffScaling" -> True,
    "VoxelCounts" -> {15, 15, 15}
    },
   Options[ConvexHullMesh]
   ];
regionHull[
  function_,
  spec :
   {
    {xmin_, xmax_},
    {ymin_, ymax_},
    {zmin_, zmax_}
    },
  ops : OptionsPattern[]
  ] :=
 Catch@
  Module[
   {
    crds,
    vox,
    vals,
    cutFn = OptionValue["CutoffFunction"],
    scale = TrueQ@OptionValue["CutoffScaling"],
    cutSpec,
    res
    },
   vox =
    Replace[OptionValue["VoxelCounts"],
     {
      i_Integer :> ConstantArray[i, 3],
      i : {__Integer} :> Take[Flatten[ConstantArray[i, 3]], 3],
      v_ :>
       Throw@
        Failure["voxels",
         <|
           "MessageTemplate" -> "Voxel spec `` invalid",
          "MessageParameters" -> {v}
          |>
         ]
      }
     ];
   crds =
    Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[spec, Into /@ vox], 2];
   vals =
    Replace[Quiet[function@crds],
     Except[{__?NumericQ}] :>
      Replace[
       function @@@ crds,
       Except[{__?NumericQ}] :>
        Throw@
         Failure["unreal",
          <|

           "MessageTemplate" -> 
            "Function `` didn't return real values over the \
coordinate box ``",
           "MessageParameters" -> {function, spec}
           |>
          ]
       ]
     ];
   If[scale, vals = Rescale[vals]];
   cutSpec =
    Replace[Quiet[cutFn@vals],
     Except[{(True | False) ..}] :>
      Replace[Map[cutFn, vals],
       Except[{(True | False) ..}] :>
        Throw@
         Failure["untrue",
          <|

           "MessageTemplate" -> 
            "Cutoff function `` didn't return boolean values over the \
values",
           "MessageParameters" -> {cutFn, spec}
           |>
          ]
       ]
     ];
   crds =
    Pick[
     crds,
     cutSpec
     ];
   res =
    ConvexHullMesh[
     crds,
     FilterRules[{ops}, Options[ConvexHullMesh]]
     ];
   If[RegionQ[res],
    res,
    Failure[
     "irreg",
     <|

      "MessageTemplate" -> 
       "Couldn't generate valid mesh. Try increasing \"VoxelCounts\" \
by 1 or 2 (can crash the kernel if overly large)"
      |>
     ]
    ]
   ]
```

Now if you wanted a hull for your function you could generate it like:

```
hull =
 regionHull[
  With[{a = 1},
   {x, y, z} \[Function] a*x + (y*z)
   ],
  {
   {0, 2},
   {0, 2},
   {1, 10}
   },
  ImageSize -> 250,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1 }
  ]
```

[image]

And this can easily be exported to file:

```
Export["~/Desktop/test.stl", hull]

"~/Desktop/test.stl"
```

And then if you want it for many parameters of `a` we make a list of hulls:

```
hulls =
  Table[
   regionHull[
    With[{a = a},
     {x, y, z} \[Function] a*x + (y*z)
     ],
    {
     {0, 2},
     {0, 2},
     {1, 10}
     }
    ],
   {a, 1, 5, 1}
   ];

MapIndexed[
 Export[
   "~/Desktop/test``.stl"~TemplateApply~#2,
   #
   ] &,
 hulls
 ]

{"~/Desktop/test1.stl", "~/Desktop/test2.stl", "~/Desktop/test3.stl", \
"~/Desktop/test4.stl", "~/Desktop/test5.stl"}
```

One thing to be wary of is that the method is pretty sensitive to the `"VoxelsCount"` parameter. When that is too large `ConvexHullMesh` can also crash the kernel for unknown reasons.

Comment: Another way is to turn your DensityPlot3D into a mesh with `ImageMesh`. `ImageMesh[Image3D[Reverse[plot[[1, 1]], {1, 2}]], Method -> "DualMarchingCubes"]`

Comment: @ChipHurst Wow that's beautiful. That should be the answer. Post it.